# 3/4" vs. 1/2" at the Shower Valve Rough In

Tags: shower, water-pressure, plumbing-fixture, rough-in, copper-pipe

I have read varying opinions on this.  Here's the detail for my install application:

- House has 3/4" Supply from Street.
- Somewhere it reduces down to 1/2" to feed existing shower valve.
- New Shower Valve is plumbed for 3/4" H/C feeds.
- Can easily adapt either way (expand from 1/2" shower feeds to 3/4 valve connections or reduce from 3/4" to 1/2" at valve.

Same amount of work either way.

What's the better move here?  Current 1/2" pressure in existing shower 5x5.